# How can I pass my current_user.id to AngularJs Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, angular-ngmodel

I'm getting my current_user.id from Ruby on Rails and trying to pass it to my angular controller through HTML hidden input>

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="user_id" value="<%= current_user.id%>"></input>
```

Debugging, my scope is undefined for "$scope.user_id", and I need this value to send it to my server.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<input type="hidden" 
       ng-model="user_id" 
       ng-init="user_id = <%= current_user.id%>"></input>
```

Comment: Kinda I resolved like the above answer but calling a function >> ng-init="init(<%= current_user.id%>)". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use *[Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)* with [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth). That gives you all devise features into Angular with a great integration. With ng-token-auth you can do what do you want and more

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use **ng-token-auth** you can create angular service with ruby helper.

```
    # layout/application.html.slim
    = js_current_user

    # application_helper.rb
    def js_current_user
      <<-EOS.html_safe
        <script type="text/javascript">
          angular.module('myApp').constant('CURRENT_USER', #{current_user.to_json})
        </script>
      EOS
    end
```